# Fill Down Formula in alternating rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So probably a simple trick, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have a Google sheet that has a number of rows which are formatted to make a report legible.

In **C14** I have the formula `=IFERROR('On Site'!K5)` 
In **C15** I have the formula `=IFERROR('On Site'!R5)`

I want to fill this down over about 50 rows or so.

I was expecting in C16 and C17 the cell reference to change to K6 & R6, but instead they changed to K7 & R7, and so on incrementing by 2 every time. How do I get it to increment by 1 instead?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following formulas to cell **C14** and **C15**, select the cells and drag down. This will create a series on numbers that will increment every 2 rows.

**C14**:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("On Site!"&"K"&ROUND((ROW()-5) / 2, 0)))
```

**C15:**

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("On Site!"&"R"&ROUND((ROW()-5) / 2, 0)))
```

**On Site Sheet Test Data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)
- [ROUND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440?hl=en)
- [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed. New it would be simple if you knew what you were doing!! :)

Comment: @JaypeeMaloney - If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would do it with a single, easily-editable formula and not use dragging at all. For instance, in C14:

`=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN({IFERROR('On Site'!K5:K),IFERROR('On Site'!R5:R)}),50,1)`

This one formula will produce 50 rows that alternate between K and R output. If you only want 46, change the `50` to `46`. If you want 75, change the `50` to `75`, etc.

What the formula does is form a virtual array (inside the curly brackets `{ }`) containing all data from `K5:K` in one column and all data from `R5:R` in the next column. `FLATTEN` then forms a single column from this virtual array. And `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` allows you to limit how many rows to see (with the final parameter, `1`, being the number of columns; even though there would only *be* one column, `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` requires that both the number of rows and the number of columns be specified).

Comment: Great to have for a different project that I haven't even envisioned yet. :)

Comment: Jaypee, is there a reason that you WANT to drag the formula down, instead of just having one formula complete the series as above?